# Get current category with children categories laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm getting children category with the help of following relation :

> Category Model:

```
 public function childrenProdut()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_categories', 'category_id', 'product_id');
    }
```

> Category Controller:

```
$productsLists = Category::with(['children' => function($query) use
 ($categorySlug) {
         $query->with('products');
     }])->where('slug',$categorySlug)->get();

     return $productsLists;
```

I'm getting children category and product of the children category of the parent category but a scenario arise where i do not have children category and i have product inside the main category on which user clicks so in that case also i want the category on which the user clicks and their associated product.

Output:

> No Child Category Exists

[image]

> Child Category Exists

[image]

Comment: Are you planning on doing anything with `$categorySlug` inside of your `function($query)`? Right now you're doing nothing, so your `with()` can be rewritten as `->with(['children', 'children.products'])`

Comment: No $categorySlug will be used outside where it matches category slug, but from this code i'm getting children categories, i want the category itself also on which i am clicking, suppose i'm clicking on top-wear which contains t-shirt and Jeans, but in some case there will be no sub category in top-wear but it will contain products, so that i want to achieve

Comment: Then it would be `Category::with(['products', 'children', 'children.products'])->where('slug',$categorySlug)->get();`

Comment: I have added output of both the case,first case is when no child category exists and second case is when child category exists. There is a difference in structure of output, In first case there is a product array, but in second case that product array is blank i have to loop through children categories array, So the drawback is i have to place two view or some sort of condition, so is there anyway  i can get same structure.